# Multiple Contact Forms - Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, contacts

I am relative newbie to all this, so sorry if this sounds mad!

I have used this tutorial: http://www.railsmine.net/2010/03/rails-3-action-mailer-example.html

And I have a new contact form working great.

The controller is at app/controllers/support_controller.rb

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # id is required to deal with form
    @support = Support.new(:id => 1)
   end

  def create
    @support = Support.new(params[:support])
    if @support.save
      redirect_to('/', :notice => "Support was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash[:alert] = "You must fill all fields."
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

And the model at /app/models/support.rb

```
class Support
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :email, :sender_name, :support_type, :content
  # to deal with form, you must have an id attribute
  attr_accessor :id, :email, :sender_name, :support_type, :content

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      self.send("#{key}=", value)
    end
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    @attributes[key]
  end

  def to_key
  end

  def save
    if self.valid?
      Notifier.support_notification(self).deliver!
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

The views however only work in views/supports/new.html.rb (rendered - views/supports/_form.html.erb)

So I can call the Model / Controller from localhost:3000/support/new but if I try and render the same form in another view from the root directory e.g. app/view/contact.html.erb I get:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

I think this is because it is calling the support model away from the supports directory.

Do I have to create an instance on @support so it can be called? If so what is the best way of doing that? I think I am nearly there. I just want the contact form on multiple pages not just in suppport/new

Thanks

Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to create a `@support` variable in each action you wish to render your form.

Another option would be to refactor the form to take a parameter, that way you're a bit more flexible.  For example, from your view:

```
<%= render :partial => "supports/form", :locals => {:support => @support} %>
```

Now, instead of referring to `@support` in your `_form.html.erb`, you'd refer to simply `support` as it's a local_assign.

Yet another option would be to refactor the form a little further, and worry about creating the actual `form` tag outside of the partial.

Such as:

`app/views/supports/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @support do |form| %>
  <%= render :partial => "suppports/form", :object => form %>
<% end %>
```

`app/views/supports/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form.text_field :foo %>
<%= form.text_field :bar %>
...
```

In this case, when you render a `partial` with the `object` option, you will get a local variable in your partial with the same name as the partial.  You maintain a little bit more flexibility in the path of your form, but can still render the meat of what a `Support` object is inside of the form while remaining consistent across your app.

To clarify, you could use this somewhere else by doing something like:

`app/views/foos/_create_foo_support.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @foo.support do |form| %>
   <%= render :partial => "supports/form", :object => form %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i have tried the first solution but it still gives the same error?

Comment: Can you post your view code, did you change your references to `suppport` instead of `@support`.  Please note, with the first one, you'll still require a `@support` variable to be defined somewhere.  In your case, where are you trying to render a support form from?

Comment: `<%= render :partial => "supports/form", :locals => {:support => @support} %>` i have that in /views/contacts.html.erb  and i have this in the form file /views/support/form.html.erb `<%= form_for support, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>`

Comment: Did you mean `/views/contacts/index.html.erb` ? In that case, you'd need `@support` to be defined in your `index` action.  You coulud also just pass in `Support.new` if you're always going to be creating one.  Finally, the `:action => "create"` is not necessary if you're doing `form_for support`.  Rails will know that `support` is a new object, and will pick the appropriate path for you.

Comment: hey sorry I mean /views/pages/contact.html.erb I will define @support in the page controller and see if that works

Comment: If you're just defining `@support = Support.new`, you could arguably do that in the view itself as well.  In this case, you'd want `@support` defined in your `contact` action on the `PagesController`

Comment: okay I tried that but it still kicking out the error so in my contact in Pages Controller `def contact
    render :layout => 'pages'
    @support = Support.new
end`

Comment: You'd need to define `@support` before you render.  Make sure your `@support = Support.new` line is before the `render`

Comment: hmm okay i feel like a right idiot, but now i am getting No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"pages"}

Comment: Get rid of `:url => {:action => "create"}` on your form.  Without a `controller` option specified, it will assume the current one `pages`.  You don't need the `url` option in this case, as rails will figure out that a `Support.new` object is a `POST` to `/supports` path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `@support` object wherever you use your contact form. It's working in `SupportsController#new` because you initialize the variable there. In all other places where you want to use the form, you'll have to do the same.